# I can't close my own question as a duplicate

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I just marked my question as duplicate. Usually I'm able **close** the question as well. But now I'm not sure why I can't.

My question [Why can't I call function that was defaulted through protocol extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351137/why-cant-i-call-function-that-was-defaulted-through-protocol-extension)

Is it because I edited my question recently?!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you edit your question after the Close Vote (for a duplicate) was casted, you lose the ability to confirm the duplicate and immediately close the question. Your question will have to go through the regular closing process now.

Note that you shouldn't add solutions to your question. There is no need to link to the duplicate in your question, and any additional links can be provided with comments.

Comment: Can you provide documentation for your first note? To be honest, the 2 questions together provide a better duplicate. Each of them on their own weren't satisfying. If I leave it in a comment, it would not be visible enough. And obviously I can't mark two questions as duplicate...

Comment: @Honey I experienced it first-hand recently. I don't know if it's documented somewhere.