# How to handle my mostly-duplicate question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, self-answer

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694986/extracting-read-only-file-from-tarball) on Stack Overflow that got marked as [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237475/python-tarfile-overwrite-existing-read-only-files).  Initially I thought this was a mistake, and I edited my post to reflect that.  But after playing around with the suggested dupe's answer, I discovered that it indeed solved my issue.  However, since I edited the question, I can no longer close it as a dupe by myself.

So here's my problem: the question did not get enough close votes to close it as a duplicate.  I figured out my problem by using the suggested duplicate, but is not an exact copy (I edited my question to show what the issue was).

I see three courses of action:

1. Try to drum up support to close this as a duplicate.  If this is the right way, what is the best way to do it (I'm guessing I shouldn't post a question to MSO every time)?
2. Answer my own question, since the problem was not entirely solved by the suggested dupe.  The problem was I was untarring a read-only file twice, and not just untarring onto an existing file like the dupe.
3. Just leave it alone, since my question is answered, I edited my question explaining my solution based on the dupe, and the link to the duplicate is in the possible dupe comment.

What is the right thing for me to do in this case?  My default would be to do #3, but I wanted to check, just for future reference.

Comment: Not trying to talk you into doing any particular thing, as I haven't carefully considered your situation, but you should be able to close your own question as a duplicate, without requiring anyone else's help.

Comment: @CodyGray Based on [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356930/5031373), I can't since I edited the question, initially thinking it wasn't a duplicate

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of that limitation. Thanks.

Comment: If you didn't see directly that the other answer answered your question, others maybe won't either. So it might be better if you don't close it as a duplicate but instead post a self-answer explaining how the other answer solved your problem in a way that is more obvious than the way the other answer explains it, so that future readers can find the solution directly instead of having to play around with the other answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the only wrong choice is (3) - edit an answer into the question. Getting question closed (1) is less controversial option than self-answer (2). You can also just delete the question.

- unless you feel this is good signpost question to keep for existing canonical duplicate - just delete the question.
- It feels valid also to raise moderator flag explaining why you can't close as duplicate yourself ("Please close my question as duplicate as I no longer can do it myself after editing it as covered in `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356929`") because this is an exception and not a common action you personally can make.
- Do nothing or add one more comment clarifying why it is duplicate - future visitors can follow the "possible duplicate" link and in the future someone can even naturally close it.
- You can provide self-answer. This is the most expensive option - use it only if you believe the question has enough value for future visitors. Make sure you get a good complete answer and not a half line text with a link. Note that while self-answers are perfectly acceptable by SO standards some may consider it "rep-grab" and react unfairly. If you just copy-paste someone's comment into answer - mark as community wiki (don't forget to add attribution), otherwise it is fine to post as a regular answer ("As covered in ... this error cased by ... which in this case was due to ...").

---

- [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/) *would be* good place to "drum up support to close this as a duplicate", but they have blanket exception for asking to act on own question -[15. Do not request action on a post that you have asked or answered.](https://socvr.org/faq#general-expectations-for-members) (thanks [jpmc26](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1394393/jpmc26) for highlighting this policy)

Comment: SOCVR forbids asking for action on your own questions: ["15. Do not request action on a post that you have asked or answered."](https://socvr.org/faq#general-expectations-for-members)

Comment: @jpmc26 I believe that's mainly to prevent closing other answers/reopen requests and such. I doubt it's heavily enforced

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth It is enforced, but it's disallowed because OP is normally able to close as a dupe themselves, without our help. The extenuating circumstance here is that OP is not able to close as a duplicate by themselves anymore.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I'm not writing all those rulez for fun. Off course it is enforced: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=39607329#39607329 among other examples

Comment: @rene what I mean is that most people in SOCVR are reasonable, and the rule is there for a reason. If there's a good reason to make an exception, I believe that SOCVR is open to it. Sorry for the poor wording.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth fair enough, let's move on.